# Display names dynamically in cards which are displaying dynamically through a loop

Tags: php

I am trying to get 'names' column one after another from mysql database dynamically inside a card and cards are also displaying dynamically through a loop here's my code but I am getting only first name from database again and again I want to print them one after one.

[image]

```
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <?php while($query_row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_burn)) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <!-- Card with header and footer -->
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card with header and footer</h5>
              Ut in ea error laudantium quas omnis officia. Sit sed praesentium voluptas.
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              Footer
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Card with header and footer -->
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $row['name']; ?>` is displaying the data from the outer loop. (not the inner loop). See the point ?

Comment: It is printing the name (check the image) the thing is it is printing a single name repetitively.

Comment: Of course, because you have two loops, the iterations of the inner loop (which in this case does not make much sense) , just print the SAME $row['name'] (outer loop retrieved data) repeatedly.